# ranger image-preview with transparent terminal background

Tags: w3m, ranger

I like the image-preview in ranger, but I also like my terminal transparent.

Is there really no way to get the image-preview work with w3m and transparent background?
(I'm willing to change my terminal-emulator if that's necessary, currently urxvt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a transparent terminal that works with `ranger`'s image preview. I use [`termite`](https://github.com/thestinger/termite) (terminal emulator) and [`compton`](https://github.com/chjj/compton) (compositor) for transparency (a nice combo when you use [`i3wm`](http://i3wm.org/)).

Here's the result:

[image]

The only problems I had were with `tmux` (images are displayed, but not always at the right position and sometimes the terminal needs to be refreshed).

Note that **the text and the image are also transparent** since transparency is handled by `compton`. This only works if you don't add too much transparency, else you need a terminal emulator that handles transparency and works with this feature (I tried with `terminator` and I did not work for instance, same for `urxvt`). 85% opacity gives me some transparency and good readability, so this setup works for me.

#### Update

True transparency [is supported once again](https://github.com/thestinger/termite/issues/191) in termite, but it suffers from the same issues as `urxvt` when you enable transparency (`failed to execute w3mimgdisplay` error, cf. @slm's answer).

Comment: It was so simple^^ just put `opacity-rule = ["85:class_g = 'Termite'"];` in the compton config file :-) thank's I couldn't be happier

Comment: Oh just one Question, how did you get the text non-transparent?

Comment: The text follows the same transparency rule since `compton` has no way to distinguish text from the rest, it only handles windows. If you want way more transparency, then you need a terminal that takes care of transparency itself (like `terminator`) while working with this feature (`terminator` doesn't iirc). In my case, I want a dark background for readability so this setup works pretty well for me, and it is much lighter than alternatives I used before.

Comment: Also, since I'm using `vim`, I have an extra `compton` rule that sets the opacity to 100% when I'm editing files in `vim`.

Comment: How ir-relevant is this one: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/ranger-users/2013-06/msg00003.html? Will there be a working image preview in ranger within from `Konsole` for example?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what terminal you're using but if it's using a bit-depth of 32 or higher then it won't work.

*excerpt - [Images in terminal](http://blog.z3bra.org/2014/01/images-in-terminal.html)*

> Side note: w3m can't render images in urxvt, if the depth is 32. That means that you can't render images on a transparent background. Be sure that you comment the line URxvt*depth: 32 in your ~/.Xresources.

This thread also discussed it as well:  - [w3m/ranger images don't work on urxvt](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=184478).

*excerpt*

> It doesn't work with transparent terminals. I always make a shortcut for a "special ranger terminal" that has transparency disabled.

Comment: any update on this issue as of today? at least an alternative to `w3mimagedisplay`?

Comment: [Ranger 1.7.2 with urxvt 9.22 transparent has image preview](http://pic.al/Pkf.jpg).
That's with ranger default configuration `set preview_images true`, `set preview_images_method w3m` and urxvt *Native* transparency. It even works in tmux but only for an instant :)