# Prevent transparent font on Termite when using Compton

Tags: terminal-emulator

Termite dropped their Opacity-Option, so you have to define a Opacity-Rule in Compton to make the Terminal transparent, *and the font is also transparent*. How can I change that? Anybody has an Idea?

In a related Question I've asked there is an Image in the accepted Answer that looks like the Font is non-transparent...
[ranger image-preview with transparent terminal background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150135/ranger-image-preview-with-transparent-terminal-background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I just answered in the other question, the font is also transparent (which is hard to see on a screenshot). `compton` (or any other compositor) doesn't distinguish the text from the rest. It simply deals with windows. Thus, that solution only works if you keep a high level of opacity (85% works for me). To have a terminal with a different degree of opacity between the text and the background, this needs to be a feature implemented in the terminal itself, but it may lead to other issues (e.g. with the `ranger` feature you were asking about).

#### Update

Good news! True transparency [is supported once again](https://github.com/thestinger/termite/issues/191) in termite, so compton is no longer required for that.

Comment: oooh to bad :-(

Comment: @sine: the transparency feature is back ;-)